# How to pass environmental variables on command line within bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

The following snippet of a bash script appears to function:

```
CF_Key=${CF_GLOBAL_API} CF_Email=${CF_EMAIL} ${ACME_PATH} --test --staging --issue --dns dns_cf -d ${DOMAIN_NAME}
```

However if I declare a variable and attempt to pass it to the script this does not:

```
ENV="CF_KEY=${CF_GLOBAL_API} CF_Email=${CF_EMAIL}"
${ENV} ${ACME_PATH} --test --staging --issue --dns dns_cf -d ${DOMAIN_NAME}

CF_Key=bsif987: command not found
```

I've even tried

```
"${ENV} ${ACME_PATH} --test --staging --issue --dns dns_cf -d ${DOMAIN_NAME}"

CF_Key=bsif987 CF_Email=user@example.com /root/.acme.sh/acme.sh --test --staging --issue --dns dns_cf -d test.gohilton.com: No such file or directory
```

Do I export the variables rather than pass them on command line?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946

Comment: Re-think your approach, and why you want to pass variables inside other variables. That's broken. In the meanwhile, just using the `env` utility would probably work in this case: `env ${ENV} ${ACME_PATH} --test ...`.

Comment: Instead of that `ENV` variable, you could use a wrapper function: `cf_env(){ CF_FOO=foo CF_BAR=bar CF_BAZ=baz "$@"; }; ...; cf_env "$ACME_PATH" ...`

Comment: @mosvy  I tried with an array approach but that seemed to produce a similar error to what I was posting.  The env ${ENV} method however did seem to work.  Thank you.

Comment: bash does not do 2 rounds of evaluation by itself. You need `env` or `eval` to do what you hope to do. And many will say, if you need to use `eval` you need to find another way to do it.

Comment: You could also simply `export` the variables first, then call "$ACME_PATH" without the preamble.